# Content Document Link Error

Tags: apex, contentdocumentlink

I am getting below error:
"Implementation restriction: ContentDocumentLink requires a filter by a single Id on ContentDocumentId or LinkedEntityId using the equals operator or multiple Id's using the IN operator."

Below is my code: Please help.

```
    List<Id> ListPOLID = new List<Id>();
    
    List<SVMXC__RMA_Shipment_Line__c> lstPOL = new PartsOrderLineSelector().selectPartsOrderLineById(setPartsOrderLineId);
    for(SVMXC__RMA_Shipment_Line__c objlstPOL : lstPOL){
          ListPOLID.add(objlstPOL.id);
      }
    map<id,ContentDocumentLink> mapPOLtoCDL = new map<id,ContentDocumentLink>();
    for(ContentDocumentLink objCDL : [SELECT ContentDocumentId, LinkedEntityId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId IN :ListPOLID]){
          if(!mapPOLtoCDL.containsKey(objCDL.LinkedEntityId))
              mapPOLtoCDL.put(objCDL.LinkedEntityId,objCDL);
          
      }
```

Regards
Harsh Shukla

Comment: First, I would `System.debug('ListPOLID: ' + ListPOLID);` to ensure you have values. Let us know the debug output. This exception is typically thrown when directly referencing a `Map keySet()` but can also occur when the bind collection is empty.

Comment: You were right. ListPOLId is empty. but i am not sure why as this should return value. Please advise.

Comment: Unfortunately debugging transaction code is for you to do. I advice you to make use of `System.debug()` specifically in and around your call to `PartsOrderLineSelector()`. I also see you have a [Question](https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/answers?id=9064S000000DU7AQAW) out to the Trailblazer Community too.